# How to Scroll whole page vertically in XAML (UWP) when screen height getting decrease?

Tags: xaml, windows-10, uwp, scrollviewer

I am working on Windows Universal Platform app.
I have query regarding Screen height.I used a Visual state to manage screen width so the app is responsive but when the height of the screen is decrease that time the content of page is cut and not properly display.So i just checked windows app and get a idea about the Scroll Viewer but i do not have idea where i place a scroll viewer so the app will properly work.I used a MasterDetail layout.

I attached a screenshot of my app so you will properly understand the issue and i also attached a code.

[image: Desktop Screen with proper Height]

[image: small height screen]

Code:It is a sample code not whole code.

```
<Grid Background="White" x:Name="maingrid">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="PageSizeStatesGroup"
                          CurrentStateChanged="OnCurrentStateChanged">
            <VisualState x:Name="MediumState">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="720"  />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="MasterColumn.Width" Value="350" />
                    <Setter Target="DetailColumn.Width" Value="*"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="WideState">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1024"  />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="MasterColumn.Width" Value="600" />
                    <Setter Target="DetailColumn.Width" Value="*"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="MobileState">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="320"  />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="MasterColumn.Width" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Target="DetailColumn.Width" Value="*"/>
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
     </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="MasterColumn" Width="600" />
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="DetailColumn"  Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackPanel x:Name="titlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Image x:Name="img_head" Grid.Column="0"  Stretch="Fill" Height="47" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>

                <StackPanel x:Name="Logo_txt_pnl" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Customer_title" .... VerticalAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>

                <Image Grid.Row="0"  x:Name="line_dashboard" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"   VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="8" />
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Name="life_time_pnl" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
            <!--Code for the grid and all-->
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel x:Name="sales_report_pnl" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <!--coding here-->
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel x:Name="stackReport"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
            <!--Report Coding here-->
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel x:Name="stackLineChart" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="50,0,20,50"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <!--Chart coding-->
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel x:Name="chartReportpnl" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,2">
            <!--Report as all-->
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

So suggest me how to define scroll viewer so the app will responsive as per height.

Comment: Which element is the one you want to make scrollable, "life_time_pnl?

Comment: @M. Pipa: i want to life_time_pnl,sales_report_pnl,stackReport,stackLineChart and chartReportpnl to scrollable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put all your elements to ScrollView control, it's automatically changing, so when your page is large enough, there's no scrollbar on the side and when it becomes smaller, it's autmatically turn on.

Example:

```
<ScrollView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" >
   <StackPanel Name="life_time_pnl">
      <!--Code for the grid and all-->
   </StackPanel>
</ScrollView>

<ScrollView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
   <StackPanel x:Name="sales_report_pnl" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
      <!--coding here-->
   </StackPanel>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: :Thank you but i need your help more so please help me whenever i comment on this question.

Comment: If it would be question on different topic, create a new question would be definitely better option. Of course I'll help you if I would know.

Answer (score 0):

Put the whole grid in a relative panel and put relative panel in scroll view, that way you,ll be able to scroll whole page.

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <RelativePanel>
        <Grid>

           //Your Page Code

        </Grid>
    </RelativePanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

And also if you want a command bar that should always stay on top still in its place then you can do following:

```
<Grid>
        <CommandBar>
           
         //Your Command Bar Code
  
        </CommandBar>
        <ScrollViewer>
            <RelativePanel>
                <Grid>
                     
                 //Scrollable Page Code

                </Grid>
            </RelativePanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```